# Spring Boot application won't quit on 'eb deploy' since I added embedded ActiveMQ

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot application hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Ever since I included embedded ActiveMQ the application won't quit on redeploy - I am getting an error about the port 5000 already in use when it is trying to start the newly deployed jar.

The only workaround I found is to recreate the environment after each re-deploy, which means a long downtime.

I am suspecting a timing problem with the `shutdown hook`.

When I Ctrl-C the application in local, it quits after a several seconds delay, with some exceptions:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: peer (vm://embedded#1) stopped.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54) ~[activemq-client-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
...
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: peer (vm://embedded#1) stopped.
```

My `brokerUrl` is set to `vm://embedded?broker.persistent=false,useShutdownHook=false`, althought jConsole shows `Broker/Embedded/Attributes/Persistent` is `true`.

Any hints?